# Which is the right React code to generate random number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I do not want the value of random numbers to change with each rendering.

```js
const getRandomNum = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
```

### 1.With useEffect

```js
const ComponentA = () => { 
   const [randomNum, setRandomNum] = useState(0)  
   useEffect(() => {
     setRandomNum(getRandomNum(10))
   }, []) 

   return <div>{randomNum}<div>
}
```

### 2.With useState initializer function

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
   const [randomNum] = useState(() => getRandomNum(10))  
   
   return <div>{randomNum}<div>
}
```

### 3.With useMemo

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
   const randomNum = useMemo(() => getRandomNum(10), [])  
   
   return <div>{randomNum}<div>
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: what is the use case? Is it going to be updated?

Comment: [Consider using a ref?](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) They're perfect for holding a value which shouldn't change between renders.

Comment: It depends on when you *do* want it to change. If the answer is "never" or "when the page is refreshed" then there's no reason not to just say `const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` otherwise the answer depends very much on when and how you want the value to change.

Comment: @JaredSmith if that line is inside a component it will get recreated every render

Comment: @epascarello
I won't update random number and never change it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry meant to specify that should be a top-level const in the module.

Comment: @t-keshi in that case you should just make it a module level const value, there's no reason to put it inside the component at all.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Humm... yes, Ref might be also one of the options.

Comment: @Jared Smith

I think you are right, the exact option depends on use case.  
If you want to change the random number only when component mount/unmount otherwise remine same.
If that so, how do you think?

Comment: @t-keshi I recommend approach 2 in that case.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks. I agree with your opinion because it’s simple and most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The useState with an initializer function might be the most straight forward approach as it will be Clearer Intent  code and the simplicity with usestate also improves the Performance ,Consistency with Other State  and its Predictable Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the random number to a variable *outside* of the component. No need for `useState`, `useRef`, `useEffect`, or `useMemo` at all.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function getRandomNum(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

const rnd = getRandomNum(10);

function Example() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Random number is {rnd}</p>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```